# How to add custom function to Tinymce editor on wpforo

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, tinymce

I start by saying that I'm not very practical so I ask anyone who will answer me to be specific enough..

I added specific functionality to wpforo like this and at this point I've added a number of new buttons/preset functions to the editor,

[Modified wpforo tinymce editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFDzc.gif)

but what if I want to add a button with "simple special formatting"?

As an example: `<p class="inlinecode"> Text</p>`

To customize the wpforo tinymce editor I followed the following procedure taken from this [site](https://www.tutrix.de/forum/wpforo-externe-addons-oder-funktionen-integrieren/dem-wpforo-edior-funktionen-buttons-hinzufuegen/) and which consists of:

**1)** I added the following code to my theme's function.php file:

```
add_filter( 'wpforo_editor_settings', function( $settings ){

if ( empty( $settings['tinymce'] ) || ! is_array( $settings['tinymce'] ) )
$settings['tinymce'] = [];
$settings['plugins']             = 'compat3x,fullscreen,hr,paste,textcolor,lists,table,visualblocks,visualchars,insertdatetime,charmap,searchreplace,anchor,advlist,codesample, wordcount';
$settings['tinymce']['toolbar1'] = 'fontsizeselect,fontselect,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,forecolor,backcolor,bullist,numlist,hr,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,alignjustify,subscript,superscript,outdent,indent,link,unlink,blockquote,wpf_spoil,undo,redo,pastetext,source_code,fullscreencut,removeformat,table,insertdatetime,charmap,styleselect,searchreplace,anchor,codesample,emoticons, wordcount';

return $settings;

});
```

**2)** I uploaded the [files](https://mrlab.altervista.org/community/forofile/d3226f48d01085142e7a2c4177e55deb/) that make up the "[additional plugins](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/)" for the editor in the following folder: `wp-includes > js > tinymce > plugins`

I've read a million guides, looked at the file structures of the additional plugins, read the questions and answers written here, but no way, I can't get there! I would more need a more specific example for my case to understand the structure/functioning and be able to reproduce it.

Thanks in advance to the good soul who will help me.